# Regex for finding URLs inside text and parse them for uri

Tags: php, regex, optimization, preg-match-all

I have a long text, where can be links like 
`schema://example.com/{entity}/{id}`.

I need to extract them look like:

```
{entity1} => {id1}
{entity1} => {id2}
{entity2} => {id3}
{entity2} => {id4}
```

I can extract all url with

```
\bschema:\/\/(?:(?!&[^;]+;)[^\s"'<>)])+\b
```

And parse it then with

```
schema:\/\/example\.com\./(.*)\/(.*)
```

But I need more optimized way.
Could you help me, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "more optimized"? You could compile the regex before using.

Comment: @JeroenHeier If I can run one regexp on whole text - it would be more quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the complexity of the question but this should do what you need.

I use the pattern to capture the entity and id and then I combine them with array_combine.

```
Preg_match_all("~schema://example.com/(.*?)/(.*?)(\.|\s|$)~", $txt, $matches);

$arr = array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]);
Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/NGrFQ

Comment: Looks like what I need! But small error is exists. https://3v4l.org/u52rR. The dot falls into the result

Comment: Any symbol except dot will fall too

Comment: @Elena Maybe you can be more specific on what to look for as "id" or what those any symbols is that is not part of the "id"?

Comment: Probably, yes. I thought about [\d] in "id". But it's only my case, I guess

Comment: Ok.. In that case the pattern should be `~schema://example.com/(.*?)/(\d+)(\.|\s|$)~` don't forget the **+** in \d+. \d will only capture single digit values.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As with all regex tasks, you can improve efficiency by using "negated character classes" and minimizing your "capture groups".

[Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/vBEYS)  ([Pattern #1 62 steps](https://regex101.com/r/SzOp42/1)) ([Pattern #2 60 steps & smaller output array](https://regex101.com/r/SzOp42/2))

```
$string="bskdkbfnz schema://example.com/bob/1. flslnenf. Ddndkdn schema://example.com/john/2";

// This one uses negated characters classes with 2 capture groups
var_export(preg_match_all("~\bschema://example\.com/([^/]*)/([^.\s]*)~",$string,$out)?array_combine($out[1],$out[2]):'no matches');

echo "\n";
// This one uses negated character classes with 1 capture group. \K restarts the fullstring match.
var_export(preg_match_all("~\bschema://example\.com/([^/]*)/\K[^.\s]*~",$string,$out)?array_combine($out[1],$out[0]):'no matches');
```

Output:

```
array (
  'bob' => '1',
  'john' => '2',
)
array (
  'bob' => '1',
  'john' => '2',
)
```

If you find that your second targeted substring is matching too far because of a certain character, just add that character to the negated character class.

I can't be 100% confident regarding the variability of your data, but if `entity` substrings are always lowercase letters, you could use `[a-z]`.  If `id` substrings are always numbers, you could use `\d`.  This decision requires intimate knowledge of the expected input strings.

Comment: @Elena was there something that you didn't like or didn't understand about my optimized and explained answer?